# How can i render HTML to asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, html, controls

i have a database which stores the page name and HTML content.

When the page loads i want to load the HTML content from the DB and render it on the page somehow, how can i do this? What sort of control should i use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`<asp:LiteralControl>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx). Set it's Text property.

Answer (score 4):

Use the *[LiteralControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx)*, and just dump your HTML content into it.

```
string somehtml = "<div>stuff</div>";
MyLiteralControl.Text = somehtml;
```